# Перезапуск бота через планировщик задач, если ошибка 0x1

Tags: python, windows, telegram-bot, telebot, планировщик-задач

Всем доброго времени суток.

Есть бот, которого требуется перезапускать 1 раз в час на Windows. Нужно сделать это через планировщик задач Windows, не через сторонний софт! Все работает корректно, бот перезапускается спустя указанное время, но вот когда пропадает интернет - в этот момент отображается в планировщике задач ошибка `0x1` и скрипт не хочет перезапускаться автоматически. Я пытался установить через планировщик перезапуск в случае сбоя - установил галочку возле `При сбое выполнения перезапускать задачу через 2 мин`, но ничего не происходит, в этом и состоит проблема. Что нужно предпринять или написать в задачу (`*.xml`), чтобы бот перезапускался в случае сбоя?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В интернете вот совсем нет толковой информации на эту тему.